Problema ao configurar o emacs
Escrevi o arquivo de configuração do emacs em elisp (emacs-lisp), até aí tudo certo, mas quando eu reinicio o emacs volta do zero como se eu não tivesse configurado ele, mas o arquivo de configuração continua no .emacs.d/init.el.
então não sei mais o que fazer, segue o código de configuração:
(setq inhibit-startup-message t) 
(setq visible-bell t) ; Alertas 
(setq initial-buffer-choice 'debmx-new-buffer)
(setq initial-major-mode 'prog-mode)

(set-fringe-mode 15) 

(load-theme 'tango-dark t) ; 
(global-display-line-numbers-mode t) 
(column-number-mode t)  
(global-hl-line-mode t) 
(global-visual-line-mode t) 
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/saves"))) 

(tool-bar-mode -1)
(menu-bar-mode -1) 
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(tooltip-mode -1)

